# Saving an empty Rich Text Field, but it is returning <br> in the UI

Tags: inputfield, inputtext, richtextarea

I have recently added a Rich Text Field to an object, the field is not mandatory when creating a new object. It has a minimum character limit of 10 (I'm not really sure what the character limit is for as I can save it when it's empty)

The problem I'm having is if I create an object and leave the Rich Text Field empty, it's returning

```
<br>
```

in the UI.

[image]

It's being used as a tooltip.

I had a look around online but couldn't find any similar issues to this.

Has anyone encountered something like this before?

Comment: Is the field being set to a default value?

Comment: @Jagular nope, no default value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why the `<br/>` is appearing, but one approach might be a trigger/workflow that sets the field to `null` if the length is less than 10 characters.

It sounds like you want 10 characters as an enforced minimum, so you probably want to add a validation rule anyway which would stop the invalid entries from being allowed.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to reproduce this on my developer org. Using escape attribute on outputtext tag can solve your problem.

eg. `<apex:outputText escape="false" value="{!lead.test__c}"/>`

Comment: This does work but is never a recommended solution. Using `escape="false"` opens you up to a whole range of security concerns, and if this is for a product it would not pass the AppExchange security review.

Comment: Thanks sperikal, but like @LaceySnr says, this isn't best practice.